# How to hide a product only in cart

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, cart

I need to hide related products from cart page.

I have created a module which converts selected related products name as custom options dynamically. When I add a product to cart after selecting its related products, I need to hide related products and show them just as product options for the main product.

I have added the code which creates custom options or "additional options" dynamically when a product is added to cart. I just need to hide the related products.

I don't want to hide the product throughout the site but just in cart. Is it possible to hide a product in cart dynamically?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the related product that gets added to the cart from showing in the related products block? It is somewhat unclear what you are asking.

Comment: How do you convert the product to options? Could you not simply remove the product from the cart then? Or set it not to show?

Answer (score 1):

In your local.xml or page.xml file you can get the Cart page handle and **UNSET** and not **REMOVE** the related products block. Below code might prove helpful to you.

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
<reference name="right">
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.product.related</name></action>
</reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Comment: Why not remove @vikram?

Answer (score 1):

In `local.xml` or `checkout.xml`

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
   <remove name="catalog.product.related"/>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

After this refresh your cache.

This is another solution.

Comment: Please please please read the question first and then try to answer. I need to hide related product which are added in cart, not the related product block.